# Can this stained granite countertop be saved?

Tags: stain, granite

Here is my kitchen granite countertop, which is a different color in the high-traffic areas!  It's been like this for ages.  Is there any fix for this? [image: stained granite countertop]

Comment: Other than the reflection I don't really see anything to be concerned with here "color variance" wise. Natural stone has natural variance...

Comment: Be assured that the brown areas are "high traffic" areas.   In the picture, the gray area on the left never gets used.  The brown area on the right side gets used constantly.  As an example, there is a spot on the counter where a coffee maker has been sitting for 7 years.  Under the coffee maker is a rectangular gray area - all around it is brown.